# tin model in Qgis

Tags: qgis, tin, model

I am having DSM and DTM data .My primary objective is to develope a CHM(Canopy Height Model) in Qgis.which i have done already but in my company they are stressing that CHM model which i already achieved is in Raster but they want the result in TIN model how to do this in Qgis?

Comment: sorry i cant understand what u are saying could to elaborate it. the link which u have given also does not meet my requirement.

Comment: if i use interpolator plugin in Qgis it is asking vector layer as input but i am having a geotiff image so please give some valid answers.