# Creating Triangulated Irregular Network (TIN) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, tin

I want to create a TIN  and view it in 3D in qgis. The tin am creating using interpolation plugin is a raster TIN but i want the normal TIN(vector TIN).

Comment: This question sounds a lot like the one at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66054/tin-model-in-qgis